# how to scrape page inside the result card using Bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`<img class="no-img" data-src="https://im1.dineout.co.in/images/uploads/restaurant/sharpen/4/h/u/p4059-15500352575c63a9394c209.jpg?tr=tr:n-medium" alt="Biryani By Kilo" data-gatype="RestaurantImageClick" data-url="/delhi/biryani-by-kilo-connaught-place-central-delhi-40178" data-w-onclick="cardClickHandler" src="https://im1.dineout.co.in/images/uploads/restaurant/sharpen/4/h/u/p4059-15500352575c63a9394c209.jpg?tr=tr:n-medium">`

page url - `https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi-restaurants?search_str=biryani&p=1`

this page contains some restaurants card now while scrapping the page in the loop I want to go inside the restaurant card URL which is in the above HTML code name by `data-url` class and scrape the no. of reviews from inside it, I don't know how to do it my current code for normal front page scrapping is ;

```
def extract(page):
    url = f"https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi-restaurants?search_str=biryani&p={page}"  # URL of the website 
    header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'} # Temporary user agent
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup): # function to scrape the page
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'restnt-card restaurant')
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('a').text.strip() # restaurant name
        loc = item.find('div', class_ = 'restnt-loc ellipsis').text.strip() # restaurant location
        try: # used this try and except method because some restaurants are unrated and while scrpaping those we would run into an error
            rating = item.find('div', class_="img-wrap").text 
            rating = (re.sub("[^0-9,.]", "", rating))
            
        except:
            rating = None
        pricce = item.find('span', class_="double-line-ellipsis").text.strip() # price for biriyani
        price = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", pricce)[:-1]

        biry_del = {
            'name': title,
            'location': loc,
            'rating': rating,
            'price': price
        }
        rest_list.append(biry_del)

        
rest_list = []

for i in range(1,18):
    print(f'getting page, {i}')
    c = extract(i)
    transform(c)
```

I hope you guys understood please ask in comment for any confusion.

Comment: Not sure why, but for all 21 restaurants on the first page - rating is 4.3 based on 232 votes...

Comment: no, it is not as i can see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very fast but it looks like you can get all the details you want including the review count (not 232!) if you hit this backend api endpoint:
https://www.dineout.co.in/get_rdp_data_main/delhi/69676/restaurant_detail_main

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

rest_list = []
for page in range(1,3):
    print(f'getting page, {page}')

    s = requests.Session()

    url = f"https://www.dineout.co.in/delhi-restaurants?search_str=biryani&p={page}"  # URL of the website
    header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'} # Temporary user agent
    r = s.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'restnt-card restaurant')

    for item in divs:
        code = item.find('a')['href'].split('-')[-1] # restaurant code
        print(f'Getting details for {code}')
        data = s.get(f'https://www.dineout.co.in/get_rdp_data_main/delhi/{code}/restaurant_detail_main').json()

        info = data['header']
        info.pop('share') #clean up csv
        info.pop('options')
        rest_list.append(info)

df = pd.DataFrame(rest_list)
df.to_csv('dehli_rest.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: also can you please tell me how can I do the same with other websites?

Comment: In your browser open Developer Tools - Network - fetch/Xhr and then reload the site, click around to see what happens, there you should see the network requests to backend apis that fetch the data. Not every website uses this technique but most do have something happening that can be recreated like this. In this example you need the right cookies to make a request to that endpoint so I had to use a requests.Session() to help me do that.